# How can i stop localstorage from overwriting itself?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

I have this code:

```js
//check if local storage contains color on component mount
useEffect(() => {
  const lS = window.localStorage.getItem("color");
  if (lS) return setColor(lS);
  localStorage.setItem("color", "");
}, []);


//update color on click
const handleClick = e => {
  const lS = window.localStorage.getItem("color");
  if (lS === "") {
    localStorage.setItem("color", "red");
    setColor("red");
  }
  if (lS !== "") {
    localStorage.setItem("color", "");
    setColor("");
  }
};
```

```
 <div onClick={handleClick} className="icon__content--container">
    <Icon
      style={{ color: color }}
    />
  </div>
```

I want to use this code on multiple icons. But what happens is that every icon is tied to same localStorage object so it overwrites the values for different icons. How can i change this code so that it does not overwrite.

Comment: Do your icons have names?

Answer (score 1):

instead of only putting a color in the localstorage you can put an object in there where the key is the icon and the value the color.

So you will get something like this:

```js
{
  icon1: 'red',
  icon2: 'blue',
}
```

You will need to stringify it first before putting it in the localstorage like so: `JSON.stringify(obj)` and then parse it again after you retrieve it like so: `JSON.parse(stringObj)`

Comment: Could you maybe implement this in the code? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to set the localstorage as object?

Something like:

```
color.nameIcon
color.nameIcon2
color.nameIcon3
```